Is it ever correct to dismiss textual content on the basis of 'historical context'?
Recently, Paul's argument in regard to covering the head, in Corinth, was chosen as an example upon which, it was suggested that, 'some instructions may have been tailored to the culture of that time'.

When one comes to examine Paul's argument in detail, however, the text of the passage indicates that Paul does not comment on any local, geographical, cultural or historical matters.
Paul begins this series of corrections (11:3 to 12:31 - Covering, Division, Supper, Self-Judgment, Gifts and Orders of Office) with the heading of keeping ' the ordinances as I delivered to you'.
Thus he is correcting what had already been delivered for them to keep as ordinances.
Paul's argument follows in regard to covering of the head :-

Dishonour of Headship (vs 3-5)

Shameful behaviour (v 6)

the Image and Glory of God as expressed in Creation (v 7)

Precedence of creation (v 8)

Purpose of creation (v 9)

Angelic witness (v 10)

Comeliness (v 13)

Nature, as it teaches (v 14)

Glory (v 15)

Established Custom, as corrective in the face of contention (v 16)


There is no appeal, and no foundation of argument, based on anything that could be considered social, or geographical, or locative, or temporary.
Every single one of Paul's ten corrective statements is aligned to the Headship of Christ, the Image and Glory of God, the Creation, the Angels, Nature and Established Custom within the Churches.
Thus, this example, once examined hermeneutically, indicates that 'historical context' is, in fact, in this instance, irrelevant.
Thus an hermeneutic approach was necessary to come to that conclusion, upon due consideration of the evidence, which consists of ten reasons which Paul sets forth.
That no other mention appears in scripture does not preclude that this ordinance is to be received and adhered to. As well discard the doctrine of 'reconciliation', apokatallasso, which is Pauline doctrine. As well discard most of Romans and Galatians. As well discard the book of Revelation as being 'Johannine'.
The argument that Paul lays out in ten explanations, is nowhere, by Paul, specified to Corinthian Gentiles.

So I would like to widen the scope of the question, in recognition that this passage is not an example of 'historical context' giving hermeneutical licence for it to be disregarded as to one's own personal behaviour in one's own lifetime.
And I would like to ask if it is ever justifiable, hermeneutically, to dismiss a commandment or an instruction on the grounds of 'historical context'.
Are there any examples which would truly justify such an interpretative action ?

"But if anyone wants to argue about this, I simply say that we have no other custom than this, and neither do God’s other churches." (NLT). Doesn't this mean that the preceding rules for head covering are a custom of the Church, not a commandment of God? And doesn't "I simply say" mean that he won't argue the point because he has no other justification for these rules?

@RayButterworth And what of the other nine statements ? And the fact that Paul starts the discourse by heading it 'ordinances I delivered to you' ? And if that was the custom of all the churches in the beginning then why not continue it (for the nine reasons stated) ? You suggest 'Won't argue the point' but Paul has already given nine other arguments . Your comment does not relate to the reality of the actual passage. Instead, for whatever reason, you postulate a situation that has not been recorded.

Do you have any other examples of Paul giving novel commandments or instructions that are not already required by other scripture?

@RayButterworth Galatians 2:11-14 But when Peter was come to Antioch, I withstood him to the face, because he was to be blamed... when I saw that they walked not uprightly according to the truth of the gospel, I said unto Peter before them all, If thou, being a Jew, livest after the manner of Gentiles, and not as do the Jews, why compellest thou the Gentiles to live as do the Jews?

There are 475 occurrences of kata in the NT and only once is it translated as "covered".  I suggest this is the source of the problem.

@MikeBorden Katakephale or kata kephale (kata with genitive). 'Down upon' 'head'. It is a matter of headship. The wording can be compared to wording expressing the 'down-ness' of the Headship of Christ.

@MikeBorden Kaluptw is to hide or cover. Katakalupto is to down hide or down cover. That is to say 'to veil oneself' (Homer and also Herodotus 2;47, see Liddell & Scott, 1854).

The injunction about head coverings in the 1st letter of Paul's to the Corinthians, chapter 11, was something I dismissed for decades after becoming a Christian, purely because others argued that 'historical context' meant it was not applicable in the 20th and 21st centuries. Their argument sounded reasonable to me, a woman in her mid-20s, so I thought no more about it. Besides, the number of ladies who used to come to worship and prayer with a head covering on back then seemed to be declining by the year, until hardly a woman in sight could be seen with a head-covering at worship.
Ah, but when in my early 70s, I realised I had been evading the issues, and that I needed to square up to them myself, and to decide for myself - no matter what others said or did. The outcome was that I started to wear a head-covering when gathered in worship where brothers were present. This was noticed but nobody said a word. Two other ladies had been doing the same for years. But this morning, at a prayer meeting, it was when I took my head-covering off at the end that a lady  made a comment, almost as a statement: "Your hat is coming off as you're too hot!" It certainly was warm in the heated room, but I just smiled and said, with a knowing look to the retired minister in our group, "No, that is not the reason." He said nothing.
Forgive me telling a little story, as Hermeneutics frowns on such things, but it's a sort of modern-day event that speaks to the situation of dismissing the principle of headship in Paul's letter. It demonstrates a (usually) unspoken dis-ease when some choose to visibly show recognition that "the head of the woman is the man" and that "every woman that prays or prophesies with her head uncovered dishonours her head."
The principle of Christian women honouring their head (the man) with a visible sign of honour in gatherings of worship is timeless. It began in Eden and continues in every century. Visible signs proliferate the Bible, and a sign signifies something. It points to a reality that is (usually) invisible. In the case of Paul's letter to the Corinthian Christians, the head-covering on Christian women silently pointed to God's arrangement of headship in the Church, including that of Christian men, with the men's avoidance of any head covering pointing to the headship of Christ over them.
This is why my answer to the question is, "No, it is never correct to dismiss textual content on the basis of historical context." The other reasons Paul also stated are equally applicable in every century: Creation, Original Church Custom, Apostolic Ordinance, Precedence, Purpose, Angelic Witness. But if the first reason is deemed insufficient, the other nine will also be easily dismissed too, as being 'merely' historic, and thus the textual content can just be dismissed. How could any Christian feel dis-ease at abiding by a silent demonstration of the head-covering principle that points to God's arrangement?


And I would like to ask if it is ever justifiable, hermeneutically, to dismiss a commandment or an instruction on the grounds of 'historical context'.

That's the question being asked, and my response is that it creates a false division. It's not about using historical context to dismiss a commandment. It's about using historical context to understand a commandment.
Everything is historical. Everything is cultural. The most obvious example is language. 1 Corinthians is written in Greek; we are having this conversation in English. We can't reach any view about the passage until we have at least done the cultural and historical work of understanding correctly what Paul was saying on his own terms. And for most of us that depends on the work of experienced Biblical scholars who do that study and translation work for us.
And then there is the question of how, and to what extent, the command applies to us in a new historical time and culture. This part is not a question of interpretation, it's a question of application. And it has to be done with everything we read in the Bible.
To take two simple examples, think about baptism and communion. Those sacraments are far more clearly continuing commands for all Christians, and from Jesus himself. And yet the Christian church has performed them in a wide range of forms and rituals over the centuries. My own local church does communion regularly. In format it bears very little relationship to the way Jesus held the Last Supper before he was crucified. But it's still communion, and it's still following the commandment. Likewise with baptism. Jesus was baptised in the Jordan River as an example for us to follow. Does this mean all Christians need to be baptised in the Jordan River?
It's entirely reasonable to treat the question of head coverings the same way. What was Paul saying, and why? And once we have our best possible answer to that question (using all the tools of interpretation available to us) then we are ready to consider the second level issue: how and to what extent might this apply to us in our time and place?

I agree. 'What was Paul saying and why ?' And that is contained in ten arguments given by the apostle. I could not agree more. We don't need to know what material the covering is made of. Paul did not specify, therefore it does not matter. We do not need to transport some material from a tropical clime. Not necessary. But Headship, Creation, Original Church Custom, Apostolic Ordinance, Precedence, Purpose, Angelic Witness : all are to have their proper status in our esteem. Otherwise we do despite to the apostolic command.

I deliberately haven't given my opinion on the head covering issue, because it's controversial. But I would say that your view is interpretation, others have different interpretations, and is not helpful for that reason to accuse others of dismissing a command.

That is exactly what we are investigating : the hermeneutic analysis which leads to an interpretation. And, in this example (which I did not personally choose) if we interpret wrongly, we could be at fault.

@PeterKirkpatrick While I understand and appreciate the desire to steer away from argument over a subject that garners strong feelings, the implication in your last point is that interpretations are all equally valid and thus if we have different interpretations that is the end of the matter, no need to discuss more because the matter is debatable. That may not be what you meant, but if it is it is not in line with Scripture. There are debatable matters but of course not all matters are debatable even though people have differing opinions about them.

Good comment, but no that wasn't my perspective. It's more about attitudes in which this takes place. So for example I do hate having arguments on topics like this, but I'm all for having discussions and dialogue where everyone can benefit. In the case of the OP, he asks if it's ever justifiable to dismiss a command on the grounds of 'historical context'. Maybe I misinterpreted, but to me that wording and the quotes felt like a put down of people who study this subject. Kind of like, You're only doing this to squirm out of what's obvious. Hence my answer.

I can see that, and that perspective makes sense. And I agree that studying and understanding the context is important so you can know whether and to what degree of it bears on a particular passage. Thanks for the thoughtful reply.

"It's about using historical context to understand a commandment."  Agreed ... and that for the reason of rightly discerning and applying truth. +1

Just to point out that the 2 examples you gave do not relate to the problem of correctly understanding the matter of head coverings. That's because communion and baptism are still carried out in all the denominations, though format and frequency differ. But over some 50 years the head-covering principle has been allowed to slide slowly out the back door so that in the majority of Protestant groups hardly a woman even thinks about it, going to worship bare-headed (as did I, till recently). The injunction is now treated as a quaint anachronism: out of date. Not so with communion & baptism.

Two points here. First, the question in the OP is not about the head-coverings injunction. It's about all commandments and the appropriate interpretive methodology. Head coverings was given as just one illustration. Second, "quaint anachronism" is an unfair description of what I think. What I actually think is that this is a highly complex and controversial passage and we need to be both humble in our own views and respectful of other people's opinions. I don't think the passage is nearly as clear cut as you seem to make out.

First, I do not see "10 corrective statements" in 1 Cor 11 - I see just two discussions:

Propriety in worship V3-16, examining head coverings
The lord's supper, V17-34, examining decorum and deferring to others (see especially Rom 12:10.

The key to understanding V3-16 is Paul's concluding sentence where he uses an unusual word in V16 -

Now if anyone is inclined to be contentious, we have no such practice,
nor do the churches of God.

The highlighted word here is συνήθεια (sunétheia) which only occurs in John 18:39, 1 Cor 8:7, 11:16.  It simply means what is a "custom, habit, practice".  Its uses in the NT shows how this word demonstrates God's attitude about "practices".

John 18:39 talks about Pilate's "habit/practice" of releasing a prisoner - this was clearly a very bad habit
1 Cor 8:7 talks about the habit of idol worship and how this habit/custom infected ideas about the meaning and significance of the communion service.  This needed to change in the church
1 Cor 11:16 talks about the custom of head coverings and the local distinction between the customs of men vs women.  Paul is clearly saying that the local custom was acceptable and did not need to change.

[I wonder what Paul might have said about some modern practices of religious garb and regalia used in some places today???]
Thus, I see nothing in 1 Cor 11:16 about enforcing a local custom forever on the church.  Some modern churches still enforce these head covering rules.  many do not.

I understand people have strong feelings on both sides of this debate, but I do have a question: why in your view did Paul include the arguments about headship and spiritual authority (starting the discussion with them)—why did he bring these to bear if this was simply “this practice works fine let’s not rock the boat guys” and not anything approaching a command?

@bob - Paul was not averse to using extraneous arguments such as baptism for dead in 1 Cor 15:29.

That section starts at verse 12, and the part about baptism for the dead is at verse 29 and is a single verse. And it’s presented as “why do you do this if the dead aren’t raised?” This is very different from the Scripture in question here where he immediately appeals to principles of spiritual authority, drawing an analogy to the headship of Christ over the church. So they really don’t seem the same.

And the passage that mentions baptism of the dead starts with and spends most of its time presenting the futility of our faith if the dead aren’t raised. So truly that part is a passing mention, a “and here’s a thing you do that would be moot if the dead aren’t raised—you show that you believe the dead are raised by this action” sort of statement with no moral argument in favor or against baptizing for the dead, merely a statement of what people do. So very different. And not an extraneous argument either b/c his point wasn’t…

…”you should baptize for the dead” but rather “if you baptize for the dead and the dead aren’t raised you’re wasting your time” which accords with his general point of that whole passage. So it’s not extraneous even though it’s also not moralizing regarding the practice.

Sorry for all the comments, but surprised by the comment in this answer that the Lord’s Supper passage is not correction. Paul uses phrases throughout like “but in the following instructions I do not commend you” and “it is not for the better but for the worse” and “Shall I commend you in this? No, I will not.” and “but when we are judged by the Lord, we are disciplined” and finally the imperative “wait for one another”. It’s hard to imagine this not being a word of correction. That and he points out what they are doing wrong & tells them what to do using imperative language. It is correction.

@bob - this is not the place for debate - if you want to raise a question about 1 Cor 15, then do so.

As a Traditional Catholic, I always interpreted this as that woman covering of head is Recognition of Right Order of Authority, as defined in Natural Law integrated and further defined through the Church.
Modernist anti-rational cancerous philosophy which brought insanity into critical thinking, and for which the West has embraced, the Godlessness and embracing and practice of policies and thinking that disregards the Nature Law and Christion values, including the denial of any differences between men & women, and other disOrdering of 'common sense.'
Instead of allowing such Doctrines to change - excused because it was only 'the culture of that time' - we should instead be concerned that even the Church has allowed 'The World' to Sicken it.

Great to see you answering. If you haven't yet, please take a moment to take the site tour and check out what we are looking for in answers and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.
